# Add Parent recursively using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, extension-methods

I have the following class defined for MenuItem

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }     
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }        
}
```

Also below is the collection of all menu items

```
List<MenuItem> allMenu=new List<MenuItem>
  {new MenuItem{Id=1,Key="Level1-A",Url="url1"},
  {new MenuItem{Id=2,Key="Level1-B",Url="url2"},
  {new MenuItem{Id=3,Key="Level2-A",Url="url3", ParentId=1},
  {new MenuItem{Id=4,Key="Level3-AA",Url="url1", ParentId=3}};
```

Now I have only one menu item retreived from DB, that is `Level3-AA`

```
MenuItem item=new MenuItem{Id=4,Key="Level3-AA",Url="url1", ParentId=3};

 allMenu.FindAll(m=>m.Id==item.Id) //gives only one element Level3-AA
```

**//But i need to include all parent id menuitem also.**

In this case `Level2-A` and `Level1-A`

How can I include this in C#? using LINQ or any extension method are welcome

Answer (score 2):

```
List<MenuItem> all = new List<MenuItem>();
all.Add(item);

while (item.ParentId != 0) // Ideally you should use Nullable<int>
{
    var parent = allMenu.Single(m => m.Id = item.ParentId);
    all.Add(parent);
    item = parent;
}
```

This will result in multiple queries to the database though. If you don't want this to happen you'll need to write your own SQL query with database features like [recursive CTE.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: I dont understand why it will result multiple queries. I have loaded all the menu items in the list. I want fetch the matched menu item and all its parent, including their parent recursively.

Comment: @Billa - If you have loaded everything in memory, you don't need additional trips to the DB of course.

Answer (score 0):

Change the MenuItem so it has a nullable parentId:

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Get the nodes, using this [Node class](http://www.siepman.nl/blog/post/2013/07/30/tree-node-nodes-descendants-ancestors.aspx):

```
var allMenus=new List<MenuItem>
    {new MenuItem{Id=1,Key="Level1-A",Url="url1"},
    new MenuItem{Id=2,Key="Level1-B",Url="url2"},
    new MenuItem{Id=3,Key="Level2-A",Url="url3", ParentId=1},
    new MenuItem{Id=4,Key="Level3-AA",Url="url1", ParentId=3}};

// Creates trees based on Id and ParentId, 
// in this case there are 2 trees, the second with only item with Id 2
var rootNode = Node<MenuItem>.CreateTree(allMenus, m => m.Id, m => m.ParentId).First();

var targetNode = rootNode.Descendants.Single(n => n.Value.Id == 4);
```

Now all you have to do is this:

```
// Get the values of the ancestors (all the parents and their parents)
var ancestorValues = targetNode.Ancestors.Values();
```